# sql server: if condition string contains another string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Here is the code I am using right now:

```
if not ( CHARINDEX(@newTblPrefix,@fname) > 0)
    BEGIN
        exec [DBS].[dbo].[form_drop]  @fname
    END
```

I want to run the sp only if @newTblPrefix is NOT contained in @fname. But this is not working. Any suggestions?

If I pass these values the sp will be executed, while it shouldn't

```
fname:form.EEN_CMS
newTblPrefix:WBC
```

Comment: Can you show sample data of what you are trying to do?

Comment: The `IF` looks ok, the problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: If I print the variables before the sp call I see that they have the values in the original post (form.EEN_CMS and WBC)

Answer (score 0):

```
IF
(@fName NOT LIKE '%' + @newTblPrefix + '%')

exec [DBS].[dbo].[form_drop]  @fname
```

Answer (score 0):

It's almost a double negative. When the expression results in 0, then your trying to say `IF NOT (0)`, which I think doesn't translate properly.

**UPDATE** I had the condition backwards of what OP wanted.

Try this instead.

```
Declare @fname varchar(20) = 'form.EEN_CMS'
, @newTblPrefix varchar(20) = 'WBC'


if  CHARINDEX(@newTblPrefix,@fname) = 0
    BEGIN
        Select @fname
    END
Else
    Select 'Found'
```

Comment: Your solution also works with the OP's version of the `IF` statement -> `if NOT(CHARINDEX(@newTblPrefix,@fname) > 0)`. So how does this answer the question?